# i can startup tomcat in explorer but can't in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

os: win7 64bit ; Eclipse Java EE 4.2 ; Tomcat 7.0.39

The exception stack:

```
SEVERE: Error reading request, ignored
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Unknown constant tag 0 in class file sun/nio/cs/IBM775
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.FastCharsetProvider.lookup(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.FastCharsetProvider.access$100(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.FastCharsetProvider$1.next(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.FastCharsetProvider$1.next(Unknown Source)
at java.nio.charset.Charset.put(Unknown Source)
at java.nio.charset.Charset.access$300(Unknown Source)
at java.nio.charset.Charset$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.nio.charset.Charset$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.nio.charset.Charset.availableCharsets(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.B2CConverter.<clinit>(B2CConverter.java:51)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.<clinit>(ByteChunk.java:102)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.MessageBytes.<init>(MessageBytes.java:58)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.MessageBytes.<init>(MessageBytes.java:36)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.MessageBytes$MessageBytesFactory.newInstance(MessageBytes.java:685)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.MessageBytes.newInstance(MessageBytes.java:78)
at org.apache.coyote.Request.<init>(Request.java:83)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessor.<init>(AbstractProcessor.java:53)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.<init>(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:265)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.<init>(Http11Processor.java:55)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.createProcessor(Http11Protocol.java:165)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.createProcessor(Http11Protocol.java:103)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:569)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Exception in thread "http-bio-8080-exec-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.release(Http11Protocol.java:140)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:654)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try starting up Tomcat manually then run your program in eclipse. This worked for me.

Comment: it still could't start up Tomcat when i did as u said ,but thank you the same